# Why do some iPhones have a low battery sound?

Tags: iphone

You guys have never heard of this before. Most of you at least. I own 2 iPhones bought in a legitimate Chinese Apple store. Whenever I use it, they would make a tri-tone dying robot low battery sound at 20% and 10%. This will sound even if you're on silent. So to turn it off (you can't) you'd have to change your ringer volume. There are no apps causing this since I wiped my phone and it still happens. I would like to make a conclusion that only Chinese iPhones have this stupid tone.

Why did they put that on these phones and not American ones?

Comment: Is there a question here that you actually want answered?

Answer (score -1):

The app "[Battery Alert!](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/battery-alert!/id416283462?mt=8)" will allow you to change several battery related sounds (warning, alert, and full). It is currently $.99 USD on the app store.

Comment: this can be done without the app.